# Why Admob ads are not showing after google play suspended my apps?

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, admob, expo

Google play recently suspended 2 apps from my account, i'am using same admob account that i used in those 2 apps, i created new app in admob but no ad is showing, i'am getting ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL, are the suspended apps the problem ??

Comment: Does changing the package id of the new app to something totally different from the other 2 apps which were suspended help?

Comment: suspended apps have packages like : dz.company and dz.company.copa, the new app package is dz.company.basketball, and no ads is showing